# Optimize "select * from table" query with 200millionen entries - DB2 database

Tags: db2, mainframe

I have simple
select * from table query but the data has ~200 million of dataentries. How can I optimize the query and still take the whole data from the table?
The database is db2.

Comment: You are requesting all rows from the table. There isn't really much you can optimize there.

Comment: IF you are running Db2-for-Z/OS then you should ask your DBA team about using the unload utilitity , for example to a flat file in whatever codepage you really need, and using file transfer to place the file on the desired target environment.

Comment: The only CLI parameters you can play with in Db2 for LUW are [FetchBufferSize](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=keywords-fetchbuffersize) & [NumRowsOnFetch](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=keywords-numrowsonfetch) (or their JDBC equivalents if any). Try to set them to higher values like 10M (in 11.5.7, 256K is max on lower versions & fixpacks) & XXXXX rows, for example.

Comment: I strongly suspect that you don't actually want to do a SELECT * on a table with 200m rows. You may not know what you actually want but this is probably an X-Y problem. What are you going to do with these 200m records once you have them?

Answer (score 0):

Enable parallelism by setting the current degree = any.  This will utilize multiple processors to satisfy the query faster.  If you have any where clause search conditions, indexing may help.